# How to ensure that there is a delay before a service is started in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I am having a service that depends on Cassandra coming up gracefully and the cluster being up and ready.

To ensure that the dependency order is met, I have the following unit file

```
[Unit]
Requires=cassandra.service
After=cassandra.service

[Service]
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre
ExecStart=@bringup.instance.path@/webapps/bringup-app/bin/bringup
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStop=
PIDFile=@bringup.instance.path@/logs/bringup.pid
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How do I ensure that the bringup-app process waits for 30 seconds before it attempts to start up?  Currently although it is started after Cassandra, I have noticed that the Cassandra cluster is not up yet and hence any attempt from the bringup-app to connect to Cassandra as part of startup fails.

I therefore want to add a delay. Is that possible via the unit file?

Comment: cassandra-service should only return once fully started. That is, the launcher should wait until the service is ready, then exit. Also, cassandra-service could make use of socket activation.

Answer (score 203):

You can run the [sleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) command before your [ExecStart](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) with [ExecStartPre](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) :

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
```

Comment: how do you solve this without having a sleep on service restart?

Comment: The fact that this works on a service restart is a bonus for my use case

Comment: Don't know why but it makes a 30sec loop for the service and `ExecStart` not going to be started.

Comment: I feel like systemd doesn't really want me to do this. With a longer delay this causes timeouts and e.g. `systemctl start x` doesn't return until the sleep has completed

Comment: I too would like to see a more-elegant dependency "connection," something in the spirit of `WaitOn=cassandra.service.output.deliverable`; this is possible what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56957751/605356) tries to accomplish?

Comment: When using the above method with delays longer than 90 seconds, the service’s start timeout will have to be increased (e.g. `TimeoutStartSec=120`)

Answer (score 71):

You can create a `.timer` systemd unit file to control the execution of your `.service` unit file.

So for example, to wait for 1 minute after boot-up before starting your `foo.service`, create a `foo.timer` file in the same directory with the contents:

```
[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
```

It is important that the service is disabled (so it doesn't start at boot), and the timer enabled, for all this to work (thanks to user [tride](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11069232/tride) for this):

```
systemctl disable foo.service
systemctl enable foo.timer
```

You can find quite a few more options and all information needed here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers

Comment: While this will work, it is an overkill for a simple delay. For simple delay use ExecStartPre and use timers for more complex schedules.

Comment: OnBootSec is apparently relative to when the box "first started" so if the service you are trying to "start after" doesn't happen to startup within 1m, it could still fire too early, I wonder? https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html But I guess if you set a long enough number it could work...

Comment: @rogerdpack That is true. However with Cassandra, even after the service starts, starting a session (with cqlsh or otherwise) is not instantly possible, which is why this approach is more convenient for this specific case. But yeah you are basically "guessing" the time needed for it to become available.

Comment: IIRC you also need to start the timer `systemctl start foo.timer`.

Comment: IMO This is the best answer because systemd considers a unit to be 'starting' when the ExecStartPre directives are executed.

Answer (score 38):

Instead of editing the bringup service, add a post-start delay to the service which it depends on. Edit `cassandra.service` like so:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 30
```

This way the added sleep shouldn't slow down restarts of starting services that depend on it (though does slow down its own start, maybe that's desirable?).

Answer (score 32):

Combining the answers from @Ortomala Lokni and @rogerdpack, another alternative is to have the dependent service monitor when the first one has started / done the thing you're waiting for.

For example, here's how I am making the fail2ban service wait for Docker to open port 443 (so that fail2ban's iptables entries take priority over Docker's):

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '(while ! nc -z -v -w1 localhost 443 2>/dev/null; do echo "Waiting for port 443 to open..."; sleep 2; done); sleep 2'
```

Simply replace `nc -z -v -w1 localhost 443` with a command that fails (non-zero exit code) while the first service is starting and succeeds once it is up.

For the Cassandra case, the ideal would be a command that only returns 0 when the cluster is available.

(May want to increase [TimeoutStartSec](https://serverfault.com/a/906068/27813) from the default 90s as well, or set `TimeoutStartSec=0` to disable startup timeouts)

Comment: Best answer on here and completely underrated! I added the note from rogerdpack's answer about increasing TimeoutStartSec, or you can set it to 0 to disable startup timeouts.

Comment: The brilliance of this is that it can be adapted to suit virtually any need, and since it doesn't have to wait for a fixed amount of time before the boot sequence can continue, it's a good method to delay the boot process, especially if the length of the delay is unknown.

Comment: This was an inspirational answer! I added this to my service; I hate arbitrarily long delays. I want the thing to get rolling as soon as it can! This was for mounting a Veritas filesystem: `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'delay=60; i=0; while [ $i -lt $delay ]; do printf "$i "; [ -e /dev/vx/dsk/veritas0 ] && break; let i=$i+1; sleep 1; done; if [ $i = $delay ] ; then echo "ERROR: Timeout; exited."; exit 1; else exit 0; fi'`

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have to put the parers around the while loop. I haven't tested it, but my example doesn't use them. They'll just add an additional subshell which is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 10):

The `systemd` way to do this is to have the process "talk back" when it's setup somehow, like by opening a socket or sending a [notification](https://serverfault.com/a/914631/27813) (or a parent script exiting).  Which is of course not always straight-forward especially with third party stuff :|

You might be able to do something inline like

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/bin/start_cassandra &; do_bash_loop_waiting_for_it_to_come_up_here'
```

or a script that does the same.  Or put `do_bash_loop_waiting_for_it_to_come_up_here` in an ExecStartPost

Or create a helper .service that waits for it to come up, so the helper service depends on cassandra, and waits for it to come up, then your other process can depend on the helper service.

(May want to increase [TimeoutStartSec](https://serverfault.com/a/906068/27813) from the default 90s as well)

Answer (score 9):

This answer on super user I think is a better answer.
From https://superuser.com/a/573761/67952

"But since you asked for a way without using Before and After, you can use:

```
Type=idle
```

which as `man systemd.service` explains

> Behavior of idle is very similar to simple; however, actual execution of the service program is delayed until all active jobs are dispatched. This may be used to avoid interleaving of output of
>              shell services with the status output on the console. Note that this type is useful only to improve console output, it is not useful as a general unit ordering tool, and the effect of this
>              service type is subject to a 5s time-out, after which the service program is invoked anyway.
>   "

Comment: It is very similar to oneshot too, simple won't run ExecStop for commands that exit shell after execution like vncservers (of course that can be tweaked to not run in background) but i mean that it runs also for background processes.

Comment: You conveniently left out the most important part from the quote: "this type is useful only to improve console output, it is not useful as a general unit ordering tool, and the effect of this service type is subject to a 5s timeout, after which the service program is invoked anyway [...] it is generally not recommended to use idle or oneshot for long-running services."

Comment: @bviktor, the documentation has updated. 
You were correct, it did not explain its purpose correctly
The documentation does say `however, actual execution of the service program is delayed until all active jobs are dispatched`. The documentation seams to contradict itself.

Comment: This still might not be enough if your service starts and then immediately the boot sequence "ends and enters idle" there might not be a long enough delay... :|

Comment: I doubt that this is going to work, because you are provoking a race condition. Expect any jobs that have already been scheduled to be completed before the one that you have marked as idle so there's a high chance that whatever you are attempting to perform after your checks to be executed before them. Your best bet still would be to directly check for the required service's availability, e. g. by looking out for their control sockets or whatever may be feasible.

Answer (score 9):

I have used systemd timer for delay a service and it work very well

```
# /lib/systemd/system/foo.timer 
[Unit]
Description=Wait some second before run foo

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=5sec
AccuracySec=1s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

see timers : `systemctl list-timers`

log:

```
journalctl -f -u foo.timer
journalctl -f -u foo
```

Comment: Best way to delay executing a program on boot but not on restarts

Comment: All I know is the above, for me, ran when foo started, not before foo started. I.e., it did not delay foo one single bit.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/24026#issuecomment-1615867761 says to use the "edit" command instead. That creates a /etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/override.conf . Nifty!